# Как создать матрицу с нулями и единицами такого формата как на фото?

Tags: python

Не смог адекватно сформулировать вопрос, буду благодарен за исправление.

**Начальные условия:**
Есть список словарей `list_dict`, в котором находятся числа (`ключи`) и их степень (`значения`). Есть список `vector` который состоит из этих же чисел, но без повторений.

**Что нужно сделать:** Создать матрицу с нулями и единицами такого формата как на фото.
То есть, если в словаре встречается число из `vector` и оно в нечетной степени, то в матрице на этом месте должна быть 1, если такого числа в словаре нет, или оно в четной степени - пишем в матрице 0. Напомню - число это ключ, степень это значение в словаре.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался создать каждому из словарей по копии `vector`, потом проходить по нему и при нахождении числа из словаря, заменять его в этой копии на 1, остальные на 0 (учитывая степень). Но уже почти два часа не могу написать этот цикл, то неправильно работает, то не работает вовсе.

Пример начальных значений:

```
vector = [3, 5, 7, 137, -1]
list_dict = [{-1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1}, {3: 2, 5: 1}, {-1: 1, 137: 1, 5: 3}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в любой непонятной ситуации... **решайте в лоб**

```
# отсортировать список значений
vector.sort()

# проанализировать список словарей
res = []
for data in list_dict:
    tmp = []

    # проанализировать значения из списка значений
    for value in vector:
        if value in data and data[value] % 2 == 1:
            tmp.append(1)
        else:
            tmp.append(0)

    # добавить сформированный список в итоговый список
    res.append(tmp)

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

а потом уже можно сделать жёстко и извращённо :)

```
# отсортировать список значений
vector.sort()

# сформировать список списков
res = [[int(value in data and data[value] % 2) for value in vector] for data in list_dict]

print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: а зачем проверять четность степени?

Comment: @Danis, так в условии задачи же это требуется или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: извините я тупой и слепой. У вас все правильно

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [[key ** value for key, value in dict_.items()] for dict_ in list_dict]

res = [[1 if num in dict_ else 0 for num in vector] for dict_ in lst]
```

Comment: а где оно здесь учитывает степень? то есть, если степень нечетная (1, 3, 5...) то должна быть 1, если четная (2, 4,...) то 0